# Dockerized gitlab use host docker to CI

Tags: docker, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm currently learning about gitlab-ci, and deploying.
My gitlab instance runs in a docker container, and I would like to use the host's docker in order to build and deploy an image.

Is there such a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If docker is not installed in the image (the current gitlab/gitlab-ce doesn't have it) you need to extend the image with an installation. E.g.

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce:8.14.4-ce.0

ENV DOCKER_API_VERSION 1.23
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
```

The `ENV DOCKER_API_VERSION 1.23` is there to ensure API compatibility between the installations. At the time of writing, you'll receive version `1.12.1` from the `apt-get install`. If you have the same version on the host, then you can leave out the environment variable. If you have `1.11` on the host, then you'll need it (if you have some other version, you'll get an error message with the version number to use).

Build the image like this

```
docker build -t myrepo/myorg/mygitlab:8.14.4-ce.0 .
```

And then run it like this

```
docker run -d --name gitlab -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock myrepo/myorg/mygitlab:8.14.4-ce.0
```

You'll now have docker available from the container:

```
docker exec -it gitlab bash
$~ docker ps
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.
Should I install docker in the container too ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try out the gitlab image, just assumed it had docker installed. Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, I updated my Dockerfile to add the docker installation and it works. Thanks !